# Resolvent is minimal polynomial for universal splitting algebra

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, galois-theory, fields

Given a degree $n$ monic $f\in A[x]$ write $\mathrm{Split}_Af$ for its universal splitting algebra, constructed by taking the quotient of $A[x_1,\dots ,x_n]$ by the Vieta formulas. This is the initial $A$-algebra in which $f$ splits. This $A$-algebra inherits the symmetric action from the polynomial ring. The structure map $A\to \mathrm{Split}_Af$ is injective.

Given $\ell\in A[x_1,\dots ,x_n]$ write $S_n\ell\subset A[x]$ for the orbit of $\ell$. Define the formal resolvent by $\ell$ as follows. It is separable by construction. $$R_\ell=\sum_{\ell_i\in S_n\ell}(x- \ell_i)\in A[x_1,\dots,x_n,x]$$

Suppose $f\in A[x]$ is separable and let $a_1,\dots ,a_n\in \mathrm{Split}_Af$ be the roots of $f$ so that $R_\ell(a_1,\dots ,a_n,x)\in \mathrm{Split}_A(f)[x]$ is separable. When $A=\Bbbk$ is a field, is there an elementary proof that it is the minimal polynomial of each $\sigma \ell(a_1 ,\dots ,a_n)\in \mathrm{Split}_\Bbbk f$?

The symmetric action on the universal splitting algebra ensures that if $\sigma\ell(a_1 ,\dots ,a_n)$ is a root of some $g\in \Bbbk[x]$ then every such fellow is a root. However, since the differences of these roots need not be cancellable in the universal splitting algebra, we cannot apply the bifactor theorem to deduce $R_\ell(a_1,\dots ,a_n,x)\mid g(x)$.

Comment: I think your phrase "the symmetric action on the universal splitting algebra ensures..." is wrong. There is no guarantee that the symmetric action sends $a_i$ to $a_j$. As stated, we could just have $a_1,\dots, a_n$ elements of $\mathbb k$ and then the minimal polynomial would be linear. Probably you meant something else.

Comment: Oh, I just meant the $a_i$ to be the roots of $f$ in the universal splitting algebra. I'll fix the question in a few minutes.